# google maps function before listener

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to figure out a way to run a progress loader while google maps processes and renders a kml.

I have a listener setup for status_changed.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(kmllayer, "status_changed", function() {
    var kmlstatus = kmllayer.getStatus();
    if (kmlstatus != 'OK') {
        $('kmllayerlist').append($('<div class="kmllayeritem">Error Loading KML' + kmlstatus +'</div>'));
    } else {
        var itemhostname = kmllayerURL.split("/");
        $('#kmllayerlist').append($('<div class="kmllayeritem"><input type="checkbox" class="kmllayerchx" CHECKED><img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='+itemhostname[2]+'" class="kmllisticon" alt="kmlurlicon">'+itemhostname[(itemhostname.length - 1)]+'</input></div>'));
        kmllayerarr.push(kmllayerURL);
    }
});
```

How do I have a function run until the listener is fired? I'm thinking something like below, but I can't think of a good condition to break the while statement.

```
while () {
  //function to run until listener fires
}
```

Working Code Block

```
function addkmlLayer_m(kmllayerURL) {
kmllayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmllayerURL, {
    preserveViewport: true
});
kmllayer.setMap(map);
var itemhostname = kmllayerURL.split("/");
var kmlstatus_boo;
function kmlProgress() {
    if (kmlstatus_boo != 'done') {
        google.maps.event.addListener(kmllayer, "status_changed", function() {
            kmlstatus_boo = 'done';
            $('#progress').remove();
            kmlstatus = kmllayer.getStatus();
            if (kmlstatus != 'OK') {
                $('#kmllayerlist').append($('<div id="kmllayeritem_error" class="kmllayeritem">Error Loading KML ' + kmlstatus +'<input class="kmldel" type="image" src="../images/delete.png" name="delete kml" OnClick="delkmlerr();" /></div>'));
            } else {
                kmllayerarr.push(kmllayer);

                $('#kmllayerlist').append($('<div id="kmllayeritem_'+kmllayerarr.length+'" class="kmllayeritem"><input type="checkbox" class="kmllayerchx" CHECKED><img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='+itemhostname[2]+'" class="kmllisticon" alt="kmlurlicon">'+itemhostname[(itemhostname.length - 1)]+'</input><input class="kmldel" type="image" src="../images/delete.png" name="delete kml" OnClick="delkmlitem('+kmllayerarr.length+');" /></div>'));
            }
        });
        $('#kmllayerlist').append($('<div/>', {'id':'progress','class':'kmllayeritem','text':'Loading '+itemhostname[(itemhostname.length - 1)]+' KML'}));
        kmlstatus_boo = null; // free the closure
    } else {
        window.setInterval(kmlProgress,400); // Run again in 400ms changed so the user actually sees the loading image.
    }
}
kmlProgress();
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you run a while loop like that, waiting for the listener to fire, it will never happen.  Javascript is single-threaded.  Therefore, you'll need to give up time to the browser so that it can do its work.  Try something along these lines:

```
var myRelevantValue = "something";
function myTimer() {
    if (myRelevantValue == "done") {
        // It changed.
        myRelevantValue = null; // free the closure
    } else {
        // Update progress bar
        window.setInterval(myTimer,100); // Run again in 100ms
    }
}
window.setInterval(myTimer,100); // Run in 100ms
```

Inside your listener, set the value of your variable to something useful, and this timer will catch it when it happens.

Comment: I think this method has potential. Are you suggesting that I put the listener inside the myTimer function and while the listener hasn't been fired (myRelevantValue = "False") then use the else to run the progrress loader? I'll give this a try.

Comment: I used this method and some of what @sheikh-heera said to create the solution. The key was putting the status_change listener inside the timerfunction.

Comment: The listener would be outside of the myTimer function.  it only needs to be set up once, and it'll fire multiple times, whenever something changes.  If you put the listener inside, then you're adding one more listener every time the timer fires, which you don't want.  I've not used kml inside the google maps api, so I'm not certain of the details there, but it should be pretty trivial to tweak this to watch the variables you need it to watch.  Just remember to set them to null when done to clear out the closures.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a function with start and stop parameters.

```
function progressLoader(status){
    if(status == 'start'){
        //show progress bar
    }
    if(status == 'stop'){
       //hide progress bar
    }
}
```

then just

```
google.maps.event.addListener(kmllayer, "status_changed", function() {
var kmlstatus = kmllayer.getStatus();
if (kmlstatus != 'OK') {
    progressLoader(start);
    $('kmllayerlist').append($('<div class="kmllayeritem">Error Loading KML' + kmlstatus +'</div>'));
} else {
    var itemhostname = kmllayerURL.split("/");
    $('#kmllayerlist').append($('<div class="kmllayeritem"><input type="checkbox" class="kmllayerchx" CHECKED><img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='+itemhostname[2]+'" class="kmllisticon" alt="kmlurlicon">'+itemhostname[(itemhostname.length - 1)]+'</input></div>'));
    kmllayerarr.push(kmllayerURL);
    progressLoader(stop);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(kmllayer, "status_changed", function() {
    $('kmllayerlist').append($('<div/>', {'id':'progress','text':'Loading...', 'style':'color:black;font-weight:bold'})); // style can be changed
    var kmlstatus = kmllayer.getStatus();
    if (kmlstatus != 'OK')
    {
        $('#progress').remove();
        $('kmllayerlist').append($('<div class="kmllayeritem">Error Loading KML' + kmlstatus +'</div>'));
    } 
    else
    {
        var itemhostname = kmllayerURL.split("/");
        $('#progress').remove();
        $('#kmllayerlist').append($('<div class="kmllayeritem"><input type="checkbox" class="kmllayerchx" CHECKED><img src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='+itemhostname[2]+'" class="kmllisticon" alt="kmlurlicon">'+itemhostname[(itemhostname.length - 1)]+'</input></div>'));
        kmllayerarr.push(kmllayerURL);
    }
});
```